# How to prevent duplicates when I append to a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to modify the below code so that selected_users remains unique after append. That is, let's append a user U to selected_users only if selected_users does *not* already contain a U.

The below code you can copy and paste and it will work. All dependencies are on cdns.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <style>
        div { width : 200px }
        .selected { background-color:blue; }
    </style>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#add").on("click", function() {
         var users = $("#users > p.selected");
         var selected_users = $("#selected_users");

         selected_users.append(users.clone().removeClass("selected"));

      });

      $("#remove").on("click", function() {
         var selected_users = $("#selected_users > p");
         selected_users.remove();
      });

      $("p").click(function() {
        if( $(this).hasClass("selected") ) {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
      });

    });
</script>
</head>
```

```
<div id="users">
    <p class="1">User 1</p>
    <p class="2">User 2</p>
    <p class="3">User 3</p>
    <p class="4">User 4</p>
    <p class="5">User 5</p>
</div>


<div>
<input type="button" value=">>" id="add"/>
<input type="button" value="<<" id="remove"/>            
</div>

<div id="selected_users">

</div>
```

Comment: I am guessing you would need to check if the user already exist before doing the append

Answer (score 0):

Forms like this commonly remove the item from the source list when adding it to the target list.

This sort of behavior would prevent the need to do the check, as it would be impossible to add the duplicate to your `selected_users` list.

Your code would look something like this for selecting/deselecting a user:

```
$("#add").on("click", function() {
    var users = $("#users > p.selected");
    var selected_users = $("#selected_users");

    selected_users.append(users.clone().removeClass("selected"));
    users.remove();
});

$("#remove").on("click", function() {
    var selected_users = $("#selected_users > p");
    var users = $("#users");

    users.append(selected_users.clone());
    selected_users.remove();
});
```

**NOTE:** I have not tested the above code.

---

If you wanted to maintain the order of users in each of your list, you could do a sort on either list when adding to it, or you could maintain the `visibility` property of each user rather than actually removing/adding them from either list.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$("#add").on("click", function()
{
    var users = $("#users > p.selected");
    var selected_users = $("#selected_users");
    if(!selected_users.find(users).lenght())
    {
        selected_users.append(users.clone().removeClass("selected"));
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to remove form the list on the left hand side.

If you don;t want to do that. Try this. The idea is to assign ids to be able to check.

```
$("#add").on("click", function() {
    var users = $("#users > p.selected");

    users.uniqueId();//assigns unique id if they don't have one
    //you can do above step somewhere else also for performance reasons

    var selected_users = $("#selected_users");


    selected_users.append(users.clone().removeClass("selected"));

    users.each(function(user) {
         var id = user.attr('id');
         var exists = $("#selected_users > [selectedid="+id+"]);
         if (! exists || exists.length <= 0 ) {
                  selected_users.append(
                      user.removeClass("selected").
                      removeAttr("id").
                      attr('selectedid',id));
         } 

    });

});
```